# JAVA: passing an input or output stream to ITextRenderer (xhtml to pdf converter)

Tags: java, itext, inputstream, outputstream, pdf-conversion

I want to convert my XHTML text to a PDF. I converted it to `FileOutputStream` but I ca'nt find a way to pass it as an input to the `ITextRenderer`. Is that possible, and how?

the code :

```
String finalXhtml=xhtmlparser(xmlText);
ByteArrayInputStream finalXhtmlStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(finalXhtml.getBytes());

 String HTML_TO_PDF = "ConvertedFile.pdf";
 OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(HTML_TO_PDF);       

  ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
      //   renderer.loadDocument(finalXhtmlStream);  i can pass a file here can i pass an input or output stream ?     
         renderer.layout();
         renderer.createPDF(os) ;    
         os.close();
   System.out.println("done.");
```

note: I can pass a file to the `ITextRenderer` as following:

```
 String File_To_Convert = "report.xhtml";
 String url = new File(File_To_Convert).toURI().toURL().toString();
 String HTML_TO_PDF = "ConvertedFile.pdf";
 OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(HTML_TO_PDF);       

 ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
     renderer.setDocument(url);      
     renderer.layout();
     renderer.createPDF(os);
 os.close();
   System.out.println("done.");
```

please let me know if I have to provide more details.

Comment: renderer.loadDocument() takes File but i want to pass a ByteArrayInputStream or ByteArrayOutputStream can i do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are using `Flying Saucer`. ITextRenderer has a method that does something similar:

```
public void setDocumentFromString(String content) {
    InputSource is = new InputSource(new BufferedReader(new StringReader(content)));
    Document dom = XMLResource.load(is).getDocument();

    setDocument(dom, null);
}
```

Adapting your code, what you'd want would look something like this:

```
String finalXhtml=xhtmlparser(xmlText);
ByteArrayInputStream finalXhtmlStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(finalXhtml.getBytes());

String HTML_TO_PDF = "ConvertedFile.pdf";
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(HTML_TO_PDF);      

Document document = XMLResource.load(finalXhtmlStream).getDocument();

ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.setDocument(document, null);
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(os) ;    
os.close();
```

of course you could also do this and skip the inputstream all together:

```
renderer.setDocumentFromString(finalXhtml);
```

Answer (score 6):

I am using following code to export HTML data to PDF with following code:

```
renderer.setDocumentFromString(htmls.toString());
renderer.layout();
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + fileName + ".pdf\"");
renderer.createPDF(outputStream);
renderer.createPDF(fos);
```

Now here I am using inline CSS to generate PDF using style but is there any option that I can use **setDocumentFromString()** function by loading external CSS.